# Dojo FitleringSelect does not respond well after dojo store get's associated

Tags: dojo

With the code bellow I'm trying to assign a new store to a FilteringSelect that had no store associated with it.

My issue is that I get a error when clicking the FilteringSelect witch is: 
*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'query' *

```
console.log("alternate on movement create");                
storeData = new Write({url: "/account/getall", clearOnClose: true, urlPreventCache: true});
storeData.fetch({ onComplete: function () { console.log("done");} });
console.log("after new read");                              
dijit.byId("far_mt_accountbundle_movementtype_toAccount").store = storeData;
```

I'm using dojo 1.8

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using an ItemFileWriteStore, which is an implementation of the deprecated dojo.data API.  To use an ItemFileWriteStore with a FilteringSelect, you should wrap it in a [dojo/store/DataStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/DataStore.html#dojo-store-datastore)

```
require(['dojo/store/DataStore','dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore'],function(DataStore,Write){
  var writeStore = new Write({url: "/account/getall", clearOnClose: true, urlPreventCache: true});
  var dataStore = new DataStore({store: writeStore});
  dijit.byId('filteringSelect').set('store',dataStore);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your help was great. Was around with this for hours. Couldn't see anything that would help me.